# why PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor only concern RuntimeException?

Tags: spring, persistence, translators

anybody give some idea why PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor only concern RuntimeException?

as some driver will give the exception such as org.postgresql.util.PSQLException or java.sql.SQLException

we want to convert these exception to others and can not be handled at here via PersistenceExceptionTranslator

it is a design cursoriness or a special consideration?

if it is a special consideration, any suggestion about to convert the SQLException to customized Exception?

Comment: Because in the end it is always a `RuntimeException`. Those exceptions are wrapped in a runtime exception by the data access technologies (hibernate and other JPA providers).

Comment: yes, your are right